# Не работает Colorama на IDLE Python 3.8

Tags: python, colorama

Код:

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background')
print(Style.DIM + 'and in dim text')
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print('back to normal now')
```

А выводит:

```
[31msome red text
[42mand with a green background
[2mand in dim text
[0m
back to normal now
```

Но вывод текста происходит без цвета. Что делать?
Если что, `init()` не помогает

Comment: IDLE не поддерживает вывод цветного текста. Добавил ссылку на другой вопрос.

Comment: Git bash удобен